# Ajax Autocomplete using jQuery

Tags: c#, php, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code to retrieve departments names from db I have problem formatting CSS of data like background and font color

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/AjaxLoad.asmx/GetBrands",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");
        $("[id$='tbBrands']").autocomplete({
            source: datafromServer
        });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(textStatus);
    }
});

}
</script>

<div id="ajaxbrands">
    <input id="tbBrands" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Any idea how to add text, like `<p >` or `<div>` to each list item?

Comment: Did you look at [the .jQuery example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for how to do this? You simply return the list items you want in the server (PHP) response.

Answer (score 0):

I can think on 2 options:

1.Add it in your php code (like rdlowrey aadvised),
for instance:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands");
while($brand = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
 echo "<p>".$brand['name']."</p>";
}
```

2.Use jquery to do it.
"Split" converts your string to an array of sub-strings.
You should edit the autocomplete function so it will add each sub-string the desirable code. Add the function's code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i assume you are using .NET, so, i wont mess around with server side code.
You can add this to your success callback function:

```
success: function(data) {
        var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");

        for(var item in datafromServer){
           datafromServer[item] = '<p class="whatever">' + datafromServer[item] + '</p>';
        }

        $("[id$='tbBrands']").autocomplete({
            source: datafromServer
        });
    },
```

The for loop added will surround every item in the array, with a p, or div, or whatever.